# How to use POST method with aws-amplify v6?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, aws-amplify

I'm trying to perform a post request to a REST API in AWS-amplify.
I've already installed the aws-amplify dependency in my Next js project, and in the Layout.tsx file I've carried out the initial configuration as follows:

```
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import amplifyconfig from '../src/amplifyconfiguration.json';

Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig)
```

Then, in the component Form.tsx (which is the one that I am using to perform the post method), I am importing it as follows:
`import { post } from 'aws-amplify/api'`

Afterwards, in the same file (following the amplify tutorial for aws-amplify v6 as described in https://docs.amplify.aws/nextjs/build-a-backend/restapi/set-up-rest-api/), I'm trying to carry out the post request as follows:

```
export default function Form() {
    const formik = useFormik({
        // Declare initial values
        initialValues: {
            firstname: "",
            lastname: "",
            email: "",
            project: "Design",
            description: "",
            terms: "",
        },

        onSubmit: async (values) => {
            if(isVerified === true) {
                try{
                    let resOperation = post({
                        apiName: 'quotes',
                        path: '/create'
                    })
                    await resOperation.response
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            }
        }
    })

return (
<div>form</>
```

**My problem?**
When I submit the form in the browser, it logs this message: 'InvalidApiName: API name is invalid.'. However I have checked multiple times, and my API name and the path are actually correct.
Any ideas of what's going on?

Comment: How was the API gateway created? was it through `amplify add api` or is it a custom resource?